# inserting an image after every page

Tags: afterpage

I'd like to automatically insert an image on all even pages of a document, keeping the rest of the text flow unaltered.  I know I can do this using something like pdftk after compilation, but is there some way of doing it as part of the latex processing?

I know that I can do this for individual pages using the afterpage package, but I don't know how to do it automatically after every page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you just want an image on every even page (no text) with the text jumping from odd to odd (relatively easy) or do you want text and images on the even page with the text flow running from odd to even under the image to odd  (relatively hard)

Comment: The relatively easy option.  (I want to insert an image of a notebook-like page after every latex page so that I can write comments on the notebook-like pages on my e-reader).  Great package by the way.

Comment: (my ereader reads pdf files)

Comment: OK I'm going off line in a couple of minutes but will answer later if no one else has.

Comment: Check out the flowfram package.

Comment: this page with image is it of empty style (just blank) or of special style

Comment: Preferably just a full page pdf image, but I'll take a completely blank page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: It's not clear to me how flowfram would help me, but thank you.

Comment: You put flow frames on the odd pages and static frames on the even pages.  The text will automaticaly flow from one odd page to the next.  The static frames can all be loaded in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,everypage}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifodd\value{page}\else\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}\vspace{\textheight}}\fi}
\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}  %  why this is necessary?
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

**Edit: warning** this is not good if you have figures, tables or footnotes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,everypage}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifodd\value{page}\else\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}\vspace{2cm}}\fi}
\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}  %  why this is necessary?
\begin{document}
test
\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

footnote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,everypage}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifodd\value{page}\else\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}\vspace{2cm}}\fi}
\afterpage{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}  %  why this is necessary?
\begin{document}
test\footnote{\lipsum\lipsum}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! (+1)  I'm looking for a solution that works with floats and footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@outputpage{%
  \shipout \vbox{%
  \vspace*{-1in}\hspace*{-1.2in}%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
\stepcounter{page}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test\footnote{\lipsum\lipsum}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, loosely based on touhami's answer.  Any gotchas?  I'll accept touhami's answer if this is ok more generally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{ugh}

\AtBeginShipout{%
\ifodd\value{page}{\setcounter{ugh}{\value{totalnumber}}\setcounter{totalnumber}{0}\includepdf{blank}}\else{\setcounter{totalnumber}{\value{ugh}}}\fi}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
some test
\caption{some}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: i will add an other solution